# How to resolve with different implimentation using windsor castle

Tags: .net, castle-windsor

I have 2 controllers that depend on `ISomeService`

```
public class FirstController
{
    public FirstController(ISomeService someService)
    {
    }
}

public class SecondController
{
    public SecondController(ISomeService someService)
    {
    }
}
```

`ISomeService` has one implementation, which depends on `IRepository`:

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    public SomeService(IRepository repository)
    {
    }
}
```

`IRepository` has 2 implementations: `FirstRepository` and `SecondRepository`.

How can I configure container for resolving `FirstController` with `FirstRepository` and `SecondController` with  `SecondRepository`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register the 2 implementation with different names and then can pass the name while calling Resolve method. http://castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/manual/windsortypedocs/Generated_IWindsorContainer.html#IWindsorContainer_Methods5

Check [this section in windsor docs](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Three-Calls-Pattern.ashx#Call_two_-_Resolve__1)